# WebApi CustomModelBinder not performing Validations for the model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing a custom modelbinder for my webapi. I am trying to get the querystring and fill the model properties. I am getting the right model but it is missing the validation attributes for the model properties. Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong? Find below my custom model binder and the model.

```
public class SearchCriteriaModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(SearchCriteria))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var searchCriteria = new SearchCriteria();
        var type = searchCriteria.GetType();

        var querystringVals = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        var keyValuePairs = querystringVals as IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ?? querystringVals.ToList();
        if (!keyValuePairs.Any())
        {
            bindingContext.Model = searchCriteria;
            return true;
        }

        foreach (var value in keyValuePairs)
        {
            var key = value.Key;
            var prop = type.GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (prop == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            prop.SetValue(searchCriteria,value.Value);
        }

        bindingContext.Model = searchCriteria;

        return true;
    }
}


public class SearchCriteria
{
    public SearchCriteria()
    {
        Param1 = "";
        Param2 = "";
        PageIndex = 0;
        PageSize = 10;

    }
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex{ get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    [IsNumeric]
    publist string MinimumVal {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Validator.TryValidateObject(..) will validate the model in the modelbinder.

```
var validationResults = new Collection<ValidationResult>();
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(searchCriteria, new ValidationContext(searchCriteria, null, null), validationResults, true);
        if (!isValid)
        {
            foreach (var result in validationResults)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
```